# Configuring an EH-WIC Card on Cisco 1941 Router

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios

I have a Cisco 1941 Router that has just two ports for Gigabit connection but wanted more so I got a four port Cisco EH-WIC Card and connected it to it.

I have been trying to assign IP address to the port GigabitEtnernet 0/0/0 because I have a cable already connected to it whose device I want it facing the router directly because I dont want to NAT its address. I want to assign the physical address on the port.

Kinldy help if you understand what I am saying.

Regards

Comment: Please explain what exact problem you're having

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That card doesn't provide routed IP interfaces - it is a switch. You can assign IPs to specific physical interfaces of this card by assigning the port to VLAN, and then defining IPs on the VLAN interface (also called SVI - Switched Virtual Interface).

Here's list of what you can do on normal, routed interfaces and on SVIs:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/1800-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/prod_white_paper0900aecd8064c9f4.html

So you need to do something like that (assuming GE0/0/0 is the first port of the switch card):

```
int ge0/0/0
 switchport mode access
 switchport access vlan 100
 no shut

interface vlan 100
 ip address 1.2.3.254 255.255.255.0
 no shut
```

Comment: I did that and I was able to assign the IP address. Thanks. But after assigning the IP Address, I could not connect to the Video Device. The Video Device has the same IP Address assigned to it and here I am stuck as whenever I try to connect to it via http, it goes into the Cisco CP Express.

Comment: If you assign the same IP to two different nodes in one L2 segment, it won't work, or it will work sometimes (due to ARP timing issues). Address properly the IP connectivity within L2 segment, and only then try to go forward. As for the Cisco CP Express - if the IP you're pointing your browser to is the IP of router with HTTP server enabled, you'll reach it - simple as that :)

Comment: Let me explain it clearly to you... I have a video box which i want to view publicly and i have been provided with a public address a.b.c.d which i stated on the network configuration of the video box. Is there a special way i have to configure the port for me to be able to access it form the internet?

Comment: Let me reply to your clear description - you need to point your video box to your router IP as a default gateway to the internet to provide connectivity, or, if you don't have enough public IPs - provide port redirection based on the public IP you just configured on the router. Third option is - you'll connect the ethernet connection from your ISP directly to the switch in the router, you'll connect the video box also to the switch, define both ports as belonging to the same VLAN and then have "separated L2 segment" where only video box has IP and router doesn't have one.